# How to call the desired value depending on the conditions

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function and it takes an int value. This function changes the image. Is it possible to do something so that, depending on the value that comes to the function, it is substituted into R.drawable.im_zd_"value"

How to substitute the value that will come into the function instead of the number 7

```
private fun datamain (date:Int) {
      binding.imIconZod.setImageResource(R.drawable.im_zd_7)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with this

```
private fun datamain (date:Int) {
    binding.imIconZod.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier("im_zd_$date","drawable", packageName))
}
```